# What modification to my code is necessary to get SetSecurityDescriptorGroup to not fail?

Tags: c, winapi, sid

Here's a link to the docs for the function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446654(v=vs.85).aspx

I've written code that /should/ work, but instead when called, errors out with ERROR_INVALID_SECURITY_DESCR. My code is supposed to copy a known working guid from one folder to another, but I'll take any working example code that doesn't error out on SetSecurityDescriptorGroup when modifying a SecurityDescriptor for a file or folder.

As you can see below, my code checks the validity of everything, including the security descriptors, yet the error '1338' still happens on the call to SetSecurityDescriptorGroup.

'1338' is "ERROR_INVALID_SECURITY_DESCR".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <AclAPI.h>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::wcout;
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::wstring;

int main()
{
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pGoodSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    LPCWSTR goodFilename = L"\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\home\\good";
    if (! (ERROR_SUCCESS == GetNamedSecurityInfo(goodFilename, SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pGoodSecurityDescriptor)))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (!IsValidSecurityDescriptor(pGoodSecurityDescriptor))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("IsValidSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pBadSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    LPCWSTR badFilename = L"\\\\?\\UNC\\server\\home\\bad";
    if (!(ERROR_SUCCESS == GetNamedSecurityInfo(badFilename, SE_FILE_OBJECT,
        SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &pBadSecurityDescriptor)))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("GetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (!IsValidSecurityDescriptor(pBadSecurityDescriptor))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("IsValidSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    PSID pGroup = (PSID)LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(PSID));
    BOOL groupDefaulted = FALSE;

    if (!GetSecurityDescriptorGroup(pGoodSecurityDescriptor, &pGroup, &groupDefaulted))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("GetSecurityDescriptorGroup Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (!IsValidSid(pGroup))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("IsValidSid Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    SetLastError(0);

    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorGroup(pBadSecurityDescriptor, &pGroup, groupDefaulted))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityDescriptorGroup Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A search here for SetSecurityDescriptorGroup turned up [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17860606/62576) as the very first result.

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I'll modify my request to ask for example code that modifies an existing SecurityDescriptor.  That example code creates it from scratch.

Comment: `GetNamedSecurityInfo` allocates the security descriptor for you, you don't allocate the memory yourself (so you have a memory leak).

Comment: Harry, your suggestion allowed my code to complete successfully.  I assume you'll need to re-type that comment as an answer so that I can flag it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GetNamedSecurityInfo() function creates a security descriptor in self-relative format, but the SetSecurityDescriptorGroup() function requires a security descriptor in absolute format.  You can convert from relative format to absolute format using [MakeAbsoluteSD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379264(v=vs.85).aspx).

(See also [Absolute and Self-Relative Security Descriptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374807(v=vs.85).aspx) in MSDN.)